# python and numpy: Get random distribution from existing distribution

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

I have a given sample distribution like for example `[1,2,3,4,6,10]`. From this I would like to get a random list of samples where the values come from the initial samples. So basically I want the same samples just in a random order (so the number of samples in the random sample set remains the same). I can do this using `random.sample()` but I am not sure how random this really is.

Is there a similar functionality in `numpy` that I can use for scientific purpose?

Comment: Aren't you just shuffling list elements? `shuffle()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/random.html#random.shuffle) :

```
>>> import random
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,6,10]
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
[1, 3, 6, 2, 10, 4]
```

And same in numpy with [*numpy.random.shuffle*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
[4, 6, 10, 3, 1, 2]
```